# Nodejs express listener must be a function

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the following code to set up an express project, but I get an exception: **TypeError: listener must be a function**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('C:/Node/cert/sn_com.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('C:/Node/cert/sn_com.cer', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var app = express();
var server = require('https').createServer(app, credentials);
server.listen(8001);
```

I don't understand why

Comment: Parameters to `createServer` ,in the second last line, should be in reverse order.

Comment: Thank you that worked :)

Comment: if it helped, please accept as answer so that it can help some one later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of parameters to `createServer` should be reversed. First credentials and the express app.